# How can I update the values in my sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here's the sql query I want to run:

```
 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE collection SET datetime=\""  + (newDate) + "\"" + " WHERE region =" + region, null);
```

But what am I supposed to do with the cursor to call this query to update my database?

Comment: You can't use `rawQuery()` to execute SQL **commands** (it is only for **queries**). Use `execSQL()`, instead. `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE collection SET datetime = '"  + newDate + "' WHERE region = " + region, null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL()` instead. `rawQuery` is used with `SELECT` operation

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE collection SET datetime= '"  + (newDate) + "' WHERE region = '" + region;
                    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(updateQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

for updating database:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("datetime", newDate);

    // updating row
    // if region is string! otherwise convert it into string

    sqLiteDatabase.update(collection, values, "region" + " = ?",
            new String[] { region });
```